# Random results from mysql sum

Tags: php, mysql

I'm new here, please be gentle. I have a MySQL database which stores values of customer orders woth the values formatted to 2d.p. This is the code I am using....

```
Select sum(Total) from invoiceitems where InvoiceNumber ='$Invoice'
```

The three values for one specific invoice are 1,080.00, 42.00 & 30.00 - the result I het is a total of 73.00. Please could somebody tell me what I need to do to amend this?

Comment: What is the field type of Total? (float, int, varchar, etc)

Comment: You should store money as decimal(15,4) in mysql

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you are storing them as varchar, then it makes sense: 42 + 30 + 1.
Try to save them as float and format the number on PHP, to have it displayed like 1,000

Answer (score 0):

I'm doing a lot of guess work here, I would need to know if you are saving the values as float , double or string values in your DB. Then we would also need to see your PHP code how you add up the values - possibly from some POST. The POST variables are string variables. if we have a komma in the number as your 1,080.00 we first need to remove the komma.

```
$InvValue1 = "1,080";
$b = str_replace( ',', '', $InvValue1 ); 

if( is_numeric( $b ) ) {
$InvValue1 = $b;
}
```

Now you can add the other values to this new value and then save them all to your DB.

Answer (score 0):

See other answers about changing the field type of Total first.

If you absolutely have to keep it varchar with commas, this should work:

```
SELECT SUM(CAST(REPLACE(Total, ',','') as DECIMAL(65,2))) as sum FROM invoiceitems WHERE InvoiceNumber = '$Invoice'
```

First it is removing the comma (using replace), then converting the value to a number type appropriate for adding up while keeping the decimals (cast to decimal), then summing them up.